# Enumerate Minipages inside a figure environment

Tags: floats, captions, positioning, subfloats, minipage

At the moment I'm working with the `figure` environment to display two graphs side by side using `minipage` which works fine. 
I want to use one caption for both and enumerate the `minipage`s with a small a), b) or i) ii) on the left of the graphs so I can easily refer to them in the text and captions. Is there a way to do this or do I need to include the enumeration already in the graphs?

Comment: Take a look at the `subcaption` package, for example. You can put each `minipage` as a sub-figure and then have a main caption for the overall `figure`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option using the `\sidesubfloat` command from the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package; using `subcapbesideposition` (possible values= `top`, `bottom`, `center`) you can control the vertical position of the labels for the subfloats:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

As we can see in Figure~\ref{fig:test} and in Subfigures~\ref{fig:sub1} and~\ref{fig:sub2}\ldots

\thisfloatsetup{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:sub1}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:sub2}}%
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```